# WooCommerce Admin Order list Custom Column doesn't display values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, admin, orders

I have "How Did You Discover Us?" info that is obtained during checkout to be included in my custom Info column within the admin orders' page in WooCommerce.

I have the same detail displayed in edit order page.

However, it isn't returning *How Did You Discover Us?* value in the new Info column in admin orders. It remains empty.

How can I get it to display correctly?

```php
//Checkout Section 
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', function($fields) {   
    $fields['billing']['billing_my_custom_select'] = [      
        'label' => __('How Did You Discover Us?', 'textdomain'), 
        'required' => true,         
        'type' => 'select',         
        'options' => [  
            '' => __('Select Source', 'textdomain'), 
            'X' => __('X', 'textdomain'),       
            'Y' => __('Y', 'textdomain') ],         
            'class' => ['form-row-wide'],       
        'priority' => 110   
    ];  
    return $fields; 
});
    
//Admin Note Section
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', function($order) {
    $my_value = get_post_meta($order->id, '_billing_my_custom_select', true);
    
    if (!empty($my_value)) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __('How Did You Discover Us?', 'textdomain') . ':</strong> ' . $my_value . '</p>';     
    } 
});
//End How Did You Discover Us

//Edit Admin Orders Page, New Column
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_order_new_column_header', 20);
function add_order_new_column_header($columns){

    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ($columns as $column_name => $column_info){

        $new_columns[$column_name] = $column_info;

        if ('order_total' === $column_name) {
            $new_columns['order_details'] = __('Info', 'textdomain');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
} 

add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_wc_order_admin_list_column_content');   
function add_wc_order_admin_list_column_content($column){

    global $post;

    if ('order_details' === $column){

        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID, '_billing_my_custom_select', 1);
        echo $my_value;

    } 
}
//End Edit Admin Orders Page, New Column
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit outdated since WooCommerce 3 and there are some mistakes.

Also, you should always use explicit meta keys and always name the hooked functions.

Try the following code replacement:

```php
// Add custom Checkout billing field 
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_checkout_field' );
function add_custom_checkout_field($fields) {   
    $fields['billing']['billing_discover_us'] = [      
        'label' => __('How Did You Discover Us?', 'textdomain'), 
        'required' => true,         
        'type' => 'select',         
        'options' => [  
            '' => __('Select Source', 'textdomain'), 
            'X' => __('X', 'textdomain'),       
            'Y' => __('Y', 'textdomain') ],         
            'class' => ['form-row-wide'],       
        'priority' => 110   
    ];  
    return $fields; 
}
    
// Display Admin order custom Checkout billing field value
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_admin_order_custom_field_value' );
function display_admin_order_custom_field_value( $order ) {
    if ( $value = $order->get_meta('_billing_discover_us') ) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __('How Did You Discover Us?', 'textdomain') . ':</strong> ' . $value . '</p>';     
    } 
}


// Admin Orders list: New Column
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_order_new_column_header', 20 );
function add_order_new_column_header( $columns ){
    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ($columns as $column_name => $column_info){
        $new_columns[$column_name] = $column_info;

        if ( 'order_total' === $column_name ) {
            $new_columns['order_details'] = __('Info', 'textdomain');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
} 

// Admin Orders list: New Column content
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_wc_order_admin_list_column_content', 20 );   
function add_wc_order_admin_list_column_content( $column ){
    if ( 'order_details' === $column ){
        global $the_order;

        echo $the_order->get_meta('_billing_discover_us');
    } 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**Note:** As I have renamed your custom field meta key, you will need to place an order to see the changes.

You will get something like:

[image]

Related: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)